# php object caching within constructor

Tags: php, caching, constructor, factory

I'd like to be able to use transparent (poor mans) caching of objects by using the constructor and not some factory method.

`$a = new aClass();` should check if this objects exists in cache and if it doesn't exist create it and add it to the cache.

Some pseudo-code:

```php
class aClass {
    public function __construct($someId) {
        if (is_cached($someId) {
            $this = get_cached($someId);
        } else {
            // do stuff here
            set_cached($someId, $this);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is impossible because you can't redefine `$this` in php.

Any suggestions?

Comment: and what a problem with factory ?

Comment: First, I want transparency and second I don't want to rewrite hundreds of thousands lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work because ctors dont return and you cannot redefine `$this`.

You can use a static factory method instead:

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $instances = array();

    public function getCachedOrNew($id)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instances[$id])) {
            self::$instances[$id] = new self;
        }
        return self::$instances[$id];
    }
}

$foo = Foo::getCachedOrNew(1);
$foo->bar = 1;
$foo = Foo::getCachedOrNew(1);
echo $foo->bar; // 1
```

Another alternative would be to use a Dependency Injection Container (DIC) that can manage objects instances. Have a look at [The Symfony Componenent DIC.](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/documentation) for this.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to use a factory method to create the object, I want transparent caching. But I looks like this is not possible with php.